# 3D ground model with open source software?

Tags: open-source-gis, 3d, software-recommendations, geology, borehole

I am looking for some open source software to plot some borehole logs and create a 3D ground model.

I used to work in a mining environment and used software including Datamine and Mapinfo Discover to create 3D models. I no longer have access to those programs, and am now doing a review of some GI campaign for a client and need to produce similar 3D models. I'm hoping there is an open-source software solution for this type of work.

The dataset I have is in Excel format and it consists basically of the borehole coordinates, borehole survey, geology logs and geophysical properties.

Comment: Please provide some more information on the data you want to plot (what is its format), on what you want to see in your plots, and what you mean by `a quick 3D ground model.`

Comment: There is nothing like a `quick 3D ground` model. Such software is almost always quite complicated. Nevertheless you can try approaches like: https://geomodelr.com/

Comment: What is a "GI campaign" ?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has NVis (via GRASS) and ArcGIS has ArcScene.  Both of these are 3D visualisation tools.  Failing that, you can use QGIS to create a 3D vector file and import that into a modelling program such as Blender (for which there is a GIS data import plugin using GDAL).